# VBA/SQL issue access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2016

I keep recieving compiling errors saying that txtlln in the where line cannot be found.  I am fairly new to SQL/VBA so I am not sure I am using the correct expressions to have this work.

```
Private Sub btnlledit_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
SQL = "UPDATE tblll " & _
      "SET [Component/Product] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllcomponent & "',[HN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllhn & "' " & _          
      "WHERE [LLN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlln.value & "';"
debug.print sql
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.Requery

Me.Refresh 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try to add a .Value to the end of Forms!frmaddll!txtlln?

Comment: added .value now I recieve the error Sub or Function not defined for Where LLN = Forms!frmaddll!txtlln.Value

Comment: You seem to be using `& ""` instead of `& "'` in your string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a few issues swith your string concatenation.

```
Private Sub btnlledit_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String

    SQL = "UPDATE tblll " & _
          "SET [Component/Product] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllcomponent & "' " & _
          "WHERE [LLN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlln.value & "';"
    debug.print sql
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    DoCmd.Requery

    Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: what does the debug.print sql do?  I haven't inputted the code yet because I went home and I am going to try it tomorrow.

Comment: Please see [vba immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx).

Comment: btw, it's pronounced 'kuh-ool' to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: That code works great, however I tried to copy/past set for other lines of input because of have multiple things to update and put in difference places from the form for the table to use and I am getting syntax errors.

Comment: nvm, i figured it out for the multiple updates! Thank you for the sub.